# How to skip frames before decoing in pyav to speed up the decoding process?

Tags: python, decoding, skip, drop, pyav

I have a python script that can read bytes of a long video. I want to skip some frames in each second.
for example the fps of the video is 24 and I want to drop those frames that are not multiplication by 3
if the frame numbers are like this list [1,2,3,4, ...,24]
, and I expect this list [3,6,9,12,15,...,24]

the problem is that, if I skip the frames before decoding in pyav, the returned frames are corrupted (when I saved them I see some noises in the saved frames) and also it gave me an error.
here is my python code:

```py
    stream_options = [{'codec': 'h264'}]
    container = av.open(video_path, stream_options=stream_options)

    video_stream = [s for s in container.streams if s.type == "video"][0]
    packet_list = []
    for id_p, packet in enumerate(container.demux(video_stream)):
        packet_list.append(packet)

    skip=3
    for id_pack, packet in enumerate(packet_list):
        if id_pack % skip==0:
            frame = packet.decode()
            if len(frame):
                frame_np = frame[0].to_ndarray(format='rgb24')
                frame_list.append(frame_np)
```

it gave me an error as below:

```
co located POCs unavailable
reference picture missing during reorder
reference picture missing during reorder
Missing reference picture, default is 65636
```

Is there any way to drop frames before decoding in pyav?
decoding all frames takes a long time

Comment: Video files would be HUGE if the frames were independent of each other. So no, you can’t just pick arbtrary frames. Depending on the codec and how it was used when encoding, the video header should tell you if there are certain frames that can be read independently. For example, there might be 1 complete frame every second, or every N seconds - those are the only ones you can decode independently.

Comment: I agree with ToolmakerSteve, you can control this only on enocding side. You need to decode all packages otherweise you loose importand information. You can skip frames when the are decoded and use only I-Frames for detection or other post Processing steps

Comment: How about the frame rate, can we change the frame rate in order to drop some extra frames?

Comment: You can try to add fps=10 param to ffmpeg you can look into pyav docs how to pass params to ffmpeg maybe it drops frames before decoding